# angularjs how to pass parameters to named function from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Inside the controller I am trying to breakup my code into named functions for readability.  However, in the parameterized named functions the scope and the injected dependency are all null.  How do access these inside the named functions.  Thanks for you help.

```js
(
  function() {
    'use strict';

    var moduleName = 'ufsrAppModule';
    var controllerName = 'ufsrController';
    var dependencyInjection = ['api', 'appHost', 'userAccount', 'userProfileFactory', 'fsrFactory', 'userFsrFactory', internalFunc];

    angular.module(moduleName)
      .controller(controllerName, dependencyInjection);

    function internalFunc(api, appHost, userAccount, userProfileFactory, fsrFactory, userFsrFactory) {

      var vm = this; //controller AS in ng-controller, do not use $scope

      init(api, appHost, userAccount, userProfileFactory, fsrFactory, userFsrFactory, vm);
    }

    function init(api, appHost, userAccount, userProfileFactory, fsrFactory, userFsrFactory, vm) {

      vm.facilityChanged = facilityChanged;

      ...
      ...

      function facilityChanged(vm, fsrFactory) {
        /*update UI then retrieve services*/
        vm.postStatus = undefined;
        vm.services = undefined;
        vm.roles = undefined;
        vm.services = fsrFactory.service().query({
            /*parameters*/
            FacilityID: vm.facility
          })
          .$promise.then(
            function(data) {
              vm.services = data;
            });
      }
    }
  })();
```

Comment: We have no idea how `internalFunc` is being called, but when it is the `this` inside that function does not refer to the controller's scope. You can verify this by adding a `console.log(this);` as the first line in `internalFunc` and examining the output in the console. I suspect the output is not at all what you are expecting.

Comment: The interFunc is a shorthand I created as  the last element in the array that second parameter of the controller's constructor.  Instead of looking for the closing "]" at far end of the controller constructor,this ensure proper closing of annotation array.  It is a style that I adapted from John Papas Angular Style Guide.  Everything worked as expected in console.log().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict DI can be done separately in this style

```
angular.module(moduleName)
      .controller(controllerName, controllerFunction);

controllerFunction.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function controllerFunction($scope, $http) {
  ...
}
```

This style is also recommended by [John Papa's Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  My style also works except when I tried to move the body of un-named functions into named functions.  The parameters passed to the named functions are always null.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `facilityChanged` is not working because its parameters are overwriting those that are passed into `init`

It can be fixed by changing

```
function facilityChanged(vm, fsrFactory) {
```

to

```
function facilityChanged() {
```

---

Edit: Attached [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/busewoyisi/1/edit?html,js,output)

I strongly recommend putting the `init` function inside your controller function to save the parameter passing, just like the `activate` function in John Papa's guide.

Refined [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bekomuqeho/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you.  It doesn't work with facilityChanged().  The console shows ReferenceError: 'vm' is undefined.  The vm created in the controller doesn't seem to be visible to the named function.

Comment: @user266909 Attached example and recommended style